# How do I publish my own steps on wercker?

Tags: hipchat, wercker

I don't really like the hipchat step and I want to publish my own hipchat step for wercker, how can I do it if I have a git repo with all needed things?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [this](http://devcenter.wercker.com/docs/steps/creating-steps.html) ? It seems pretty extensive, maybe if you try this and run in to problems you can ask a more specific question?